# Integrate a delete option in my discord bot

Tags: discord.py, bots

I am creating a bot for my discord and I have been trying for 3 days to integrate the delete option and I encounter the following problem:

```
in delete
    messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=number_of_messages + 1).flatten()
AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'flatten'


raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'flatten'
```

Code:

```
@bot.command(name='del')
async def delete(ctx: commands.Context, number_of_messages: int):
    messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=number_of_messages + 1).flatten()

    for each_message in messages:
        await each_message.delete()
```

python version :  3.10.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In discord.py 2.0 the [`.flatten()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#moving-away-from-custom-asynciterator) method was removed since the introduction of [async list comprehensions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0530/).

```py
@bot.command(name='del')
async def delete(ctx: commands.Context, number_of_messages: int):
    messages = [message async for message in ctx.channel.history(number_of_messages + 1)]

    for each_message in messages:
        await each_message.delete()
```

This is a bad solution, though. Use the [`channel.purge()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge) method since it bulk deletes messages:

```py
@bot.command(name='del')
async def delete(ctx: commands.Context, number_of_messages: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=number_of_messages + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and your suggestion. It seems the purge method is the best adapter for my expectation